# Kohanim on Rosh Hashanah

Tags: kohen-priest, torah-service, birchas-kohanim

Is it permissible to have the same kohen have a Torah Aliyah in two different rooms? Is it permissible to have the same kohen duchen in two different rooms?

Comment: "Is it permissible to have the same kohen have a Torah Aliyah in both rooms?" Without addressing if it's permissible, it's pointless. There's no disrespect to a kohein if he's not there.

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe he's the baal korei and the only kohen at both

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Adam and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us. Also can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?